# Parsing Video from JSON to Swift ( SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

i'm somewhat new to working with JSON data in Swift so I have a problem with it.
I did fetch all the vars from JSON into SwiftUI, working really well, except I don't know how to decode videos from JSON and add them to SwiftUI
From what I see in the JSON there is a Video Endpoint
( ex. base]/uploads/companymedia/[id]/[value].mp4", )
But, im not sure how to decode it, and put it so it works in my SwiftUI file. Currently its fetching everything ( text, subtext, images ) just not videos and on the part where the video should be it just shows an image.
The code is this:

````
   HStack{
                    
                    Text(post.title)
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: shareButton){
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .font(.system(size: 22))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            .padding(.top, 15)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    }
                }
                
                                
                if let text = post.text{
                    Text(text)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label).opacity(0.5))
                }
                
                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: post.date))
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label).opacity(0.5))

            }
            .padding(16)
            
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                PagedScrollView(numberOfPages: post.images.count){
                    HStack(spacing: 0){
                        ForEach(post.images, id: \.self){ image in
                            KFImage(URL(string: image)!)
                                .setProcessor(processor)
                                .cacheOriginalImage(true)
                                .backgroundDecode(true)
                                .loadImmediately()
                                .fade(duration: 1)
                                .placeholder({
                                    Color.red
                                })
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                                .clipped()
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            }
            .frame(height: 400)
            HStack{
                Locallike(isLiked: $isLiked)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .padding(.top,15)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                    SmileLike(isSmiled: $isSmiled)
                    .font(.system(size: 22))
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal,15)
                Spacer()
                
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CommentsView(postId: post.id)) {
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                        .font(.system(size: 22))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .padding(.top, 15)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        .padding(.horizontal,15)
                    
               
                        
                    
                
                            }
                
              

                    }
                  

               



                        }
            
           
            
            
        
        .background(Color(.label).opacity(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Presumably, you've looked up how to play a video in SwiftUI. But, there doesn't look like there's any attempt in your code. You say that right now, "the part where the video should be it just shows an image", but all you have is code to display an image. Can you clarify what this issue is?

Comment: "how to decode videos from JSON"  What does decoding a video from JSON mean?  You mean, your JSON dataset contains a string pointing to the location of a video clip?

Comment: How do you expect someone to show you how to "decode videos from JSON" if you don't include the JSON data in the question?

Comment: Lots of mean spirited people responding. How about some polite behavior in responses?