# Playing video from parsed JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, avplayer

so I've been parsing my JSON into the app. But the actual videourl which is supposed to play a video instead shows a simple image. In my PostsModel I parsed it and created an enum for if it is an image or video as you can see in the code below

```
  enum PostType{
      case images([String])
      case video(String)
    }
    
    let id: String
    let title: String
    var text: String?
    let images: [String]
    let category: Category
    let date_start: String
    let date: Date
    var videourl: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case text
        case images
        case date_start
        case videourl
        case category = "category_id"
    }
```

And then in the init I parsed it

```
  videourl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .videourl)
```

And for the PostsView in SwiftUI I added a case as well. I'm not that familiar with SwiftUI to actually make the AV Player play it. It either crashes or does nothing. If someone could point me towards the right direction of it working it would be greatly appreciated.

The code in PostsView is as follows

```
if let videourl = post.videourl{
//Should do something to make the AV Player actually display the video here
}
else{
//should be image stuff ( I can make this work, just not the video player )
}
```

Comment: You posted basically the same question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477543/parsing-video-from-json-to-swift-swiftui). You still haven't shown your JSON, or answered either of the questions that were left as comments to try to clarify yesterday's question.

Comment: I dont need to decode it anymore, I just need to fetch it into SwiftUI.

Comment: So your question is just how to display a video in SwiftUI? As I said yesterday, there are plenty of articles about that, but it doesn't seem that you've attempted to code one up. Can you say what you've tried in terms of displaying the video? And provide a sample URL that you're giving it?

Comment: Yes, i tried https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-play-movies-with-videoplayer along these lines, but im not sure how to fetch the url which is presented as post.videourl instead of a normal http link

Comment: How is it different than a normal `http` link? You haven't shown your JSON or an example URL.

Comment: I think you dont understand me. Can I use post.videourl instead of the full video link, thats what I meant

Comment: I don't know what `post.videourl` contains or how it's different than a "full video link" as you call it. Its name suggests that it's a URL, but only you know at this point what it contains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232254/discussion-between-saxonsxexe-and-jnpdx).